# How to use 'require' instead of 'import' statements

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

In JavaScript, node.js, when I export module using CommonJS style, such as

```
module.export.foo = (param) => {
    // do sth here
   return value
}
```

and I start typing `foo` in the other file in my node.js project, VS Code suggests: "Auto import from 'path/to/file'" after pressing enter, VS Code inserts statement at the top of the file:

```
import { foo } from 'path/to/file'
```

I'd like VS code to paste following code instead:

```
const { foo } = require('path/to/file')
```

Is it possible?

My `jsconfig.json` looks like that:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es6"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "__tests__/**/*"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Custom model training for TS/JS to the IntelliCode extension for VS Code doesn't currently seem possible according to [issue #26](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/26).

Answer (score 2):

Coming in v1.46 this should work better:

> #### CommonJS Auto imports
>
> If VS Code detects that you are working in a CommonJS style JavaScript
>   module, auto imports will now use `require` instead of `import`.

from [v1.46 release notes: CommonJS imports](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#commonjs-auto-imports)

Comment: Is there a way to use import syntax by default?

Comment: @BexultanMyrzatayev I came here for that answer as well

Comment: @BexultanMyrzatayev See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69126761/6463558