# VS Code imports using the require syntax in React test cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-testing-library

Little lately, I have found that my react project in the VS Code IDE is using require syntax in the test cases when I'm doing auto import from the suggestions. Could anyone please help?

I'm using React testing library and here's how it looks like.

```
const { render } = require("@testing-library/react");
const { default: Home } = require("../Home");

describe("Home", () => {
  it("should render Search page", () => {
    const { container } = render(<Home />);
  });
});
```

I have a `jsconfig.json` file as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the new feature [CommonJS auto imports](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#commonjs-auto-imports), we know:

> If VS Code detects that you are working in a CommonJS style JavaScript module, auto imports will now use `require` instead of `import`.

You can set `compilerOptions.module` to `es2015` for [jsconfig.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_jsconfig-options). So that the js file will be detected as ESM, auto imports will use `import` instead of `require`.

`jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015"
  },
}
```

```js
// auto imports use `import` keyword.
import { render } from 'react-dom';

describe('Home', () => {
  it('should render Search page', () => {
    render
  });
});
```

For more info about when VS code uses `require`, see [shouldUseRequire](https://github.com/andrewbranch/TypeScript/blob/3e414691cdf268f88bb9a90ec2704ceb8f40d231/src/services/codefixes/importFixes.ts#L365) function.

P.S If it does not work, try to reload the window of VS code after adding this configuration.

Comment: I added a `jsconfig.json` in the root of my project with ```{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS"
  },
}``` shouldnt that force it to use `require`???